# Whats the difference between $_ and !$?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-expansion

I've always used `!$` to refer to the last argument of the previous command.

e.g.

```
~/dir » mkdir birthday
~/dir » cd !$
~/dir » cd birthday
```

However I've started seeing tutorials use `$_` in place of `!$`

I've tested the two and the only difference I've noticed is subtle, but it appears that `$_` will evaluate and execute the command whereas `!$` will let you sanity check the output before hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but is this the only difference between `$_` and `!$`?

Update: flagged as a duplicate? This question may be answered by the accepted answer for the suggested question, but only because the answer is more detailed than the question required.

Searching for **What does _$ mean?** does yield the suggested duplicate, however I already and I knew prior to asking what `!$` did, and there is nothing that suggests that question might also answer other questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run `man bash` and search for section *Special Parameters*. For `_` you'll find:

> expands to the last argument to the
> previous command, *after expansion*.

A slightly more verbose version might be...

> expands to the last argument to the previous command as it was received by that command, i.e. after going through Shell Expansion

Instead of explaining that further I think a couple examples will really help.

**Example 1**

```
$ echo "$(date +%s)" # %s is seconds since epoch
1536984661
$ echo $_ !$ "$(date +%s)" # don't hit enter until a few seconds pass
1536984661 1536984665 1536984665
```

`$_` gets the actual value passed to the preceding `echo` so it resolves to a seconds-since-epoch value in the past. Meanwhile, since `!$` is simply replaced with the *typed* value of the last argument, i.e. `"$(date +%s)"`, it resolves to the same later time as the argument that follows it.

**Example 2**

```
$ foo='a b c'
$ echo "$foo"  # expands to single arg: 'a b c'
a b c
$ echo "$_"
a b c
$ #---------
$ echo $foo    # expands to three args: a b c
a b c
$ echo "$_"
c
```

Notice that the second time `$foo` was echoed it wasn't quoted. So before being passed to `echo` it went through variable/parameter expansion and word splitting. That expansion/splitting resulted in *a*, *b* and *c* being passed as three separate parameters to `echo` and since `$_` is assigned just the last one we see only *c*. (If `!$` were used *a b c* would still be displayed since, again, it's just replaced with the value you typed in, i.e. `$foo`.)

In addition to the above there's a bit more practical value to `$_` versus `!$` because the former *is a variable*. So, for example, if the last parameter were `/some/file/path.txt` you could get it's length `${#_} -> 19`, extract filename only `${_##*/} -> path.txt`, change the root `${_//some/other} -> /other/file/path.txt` and so on. Can't do any of that with `!$`.

---

Finally, note that `$_` has different meanings in other contexts:

> At shell startup, set to the absolute pathname used to invoke the shell or shell script being executed as passed in  the  environment or argument list.

...and...

> Also set to the full pathname used
> to invoke each command executed and placed in the environment exported
> to that command.

...and...

> When  checking mail, this parameter holds the name
> of the mail file currently being checked.